# How can I make an API call that depends on a value which is set by another call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a login function where I am setting a token, that token is saved in a redux store, then, right after the login occurs, I need to make another call to the api which will feed the home screen with data. But in order to make that call, I need the token.

This is the homescreen component where I need to make that call:

```
// imports

import styles from '../../styles/HomeScreenStyles';
import { passengersDataAction } from './actions/homeScreen';

class HomeScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.GetPassengersData();
  }

  GetPassengersData = async () => {
    // userToken is coming from the store
    const { passengersDataActionHandler, userToken } = this.props;
    if (userToken && userToken !== null) {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          'http://myAPI/public/api/getPassengers',
          {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${userToken}`,
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
          },
        );
        const responseJson = await response.json();
          passengersDataActionHandler(responseJson.success.data);      
      } // catch ...
    }
  };

  render() {
    return <TabView style={styles.container} />;
  }
}

// export
```

By the time `GetPassengersData` is called `userToken` is not present yet, so my request goes directly to the catch error callback.

How can I handle it?

EDIT: 
The API call I put above is the one where I need the token.

Call to get the logindata:

```
import { Alert, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { has } from 'lodash';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const FetchLoginData = async (
  username,
  password,
  navigation,
  userTokenActionHandler,
) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      'http://myAPI/public/api/driverlogin',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ email: username, password }),
      },
    );
    const responseJson = await response.json();
    if (has(responseJson, 'error')) {
      Alert.alert('Error', 'Please check your credentials.');
    } else {
      // HERE I SET THE TOKEN
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', responseJson.success.token);
      userTokenActionHandler(responseJson.success.token);
      navigation.navigate('App');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    Alert.alert(
      'Error',
      'There was an error with your request, please try again later.',
    );
  }
};

FetchLoginData.propTypes = {
  navigation: PropTypes.shape({}).isRequired,
  userTokenActionHandler: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default FetchLoginData;
```

Comment: Can we see the call that gets the token? I assume it is stored in this.props?

Comment: Hi @MarkWheeler see my last update. I just posted the code.

Comment: maybe you should use componentWillReceiveProps to run GetPassengersData function. Because CDM just run one and not watch the change of props, what CWRP does.

Comment: @TamDc according to react docs -> `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps` -> https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: @Non You can set `userToken` is a `state` of `HomeScreen` component and then use `getDerivedStateFromProps` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your second call here :

```
try {
    const response = await fetch(
      'http://myAPI/public/api/getPassengers',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${userToken}`,
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      },
    );
   const responseJson = await response.json();
      passengersDataActionHandler(responseJson.success.data);  

   // **put second call here you have token here send it to second api call**

  }
```

Comment: Mmm The API call I put above is the one where I need the token.